# Not sure when exactly will be applying for a PhD (and what program) - is it a good idea to ask for letters of recommendation now?

Tags: application, recommendation-letter, united-kingdom, europe

I graduated last year (MEng) and since have been working in an office software development job. I figured that I want to start pursuing research, in order to contribute most to the issues I care about (dealing with current / imminent environmental troubles). However, I am not yet clear what flavour of tech research my skills/interests are most suitable for, as this would be a career shift for me. I'm planning to quit my job later this year and get involved in various relevant non-profit organisations, personal projects/research and short internships to gain more appreciation of the current state of affairs in the field.

I'm planning to apply for Autumn 2017 entry but there is a high chance I will not have all the necessary information to apply for that date and will have to delay it for additional year. Thinking about the practical implications of that - **Is it a good idea to ask my contacts from the university to write me letters of recommendation now, while they still remember me (reasonably) well?**

I guess that depends on a variety of factors. In particular I am not aware at all how programme-specific are such letters meant to be. Are referrers supposed to tailor them to my research proposal or are they more generic? Will they need to be much different if I apply for, say, Robotics (applications in disaster recovery) versus research in using low-cost tech to grow food in harsh conditions?

Detail: I am mostly thinking of doing a doctorate in Europe (UK in particular) but I'm pretty flexible.

Comment: It will depend on the relationship you have with your previous supervisors/contacts from the University and their personality. If there are exceptional mentors that are ready to support you, they will be more than happy to help. First you need to make up your mind and choose what sounds best for you, let's say 3 options. Then the best would be to contact them to know how they are doing. Then propose a meeting/ video call and discuss the situation with them if they agree. Hope that helps